# What is the main inner conflict in Harry Potter?

Tags: character-development

Recent events have compelled me to study inner conflicts. Having arrived at this decision, I turned to one of my favorite books in an attempt to identify said conflict. However, upon opening *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's (Philosopher's) Stone* I realized that I hadn't the faintest clue what the main inner conflict was.

The only thing that feels remotely like an inner conflict, is Harry's subtle denial that he can't be a wizard, in the face of all that is changing about him. I feel certain this is *an* inner conflict, but I doubt it is the main one.

What is the main inner conflict in the first *Harry Potter* book?

Comment: Maybe this book is more about external conflict?

Comment: The community has decided that analyzing existing works is off-topic unless it *directly* pertains to your own writing. You're heading in the right direction, but this particular question is still not quite there. This question will likely be put on hold; sorry.

Comment: Hmm, I was not aware of that, Lauren. Well, the question is answered now, so no damage done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children begin reading books without conflict at all (colors and shapes), and then advance to simple external conflicts (Dr. Seuss), and eventually discover inner conflict around adolescence.

Harry Potter's story grew with the character, and the audience. The earliest book provided little in the way of internal narrative at all. As the character grew, so did the complexity of both the characters and the readers. The characters developed more extreme emotions as they faced more extreme circumstances, each character slowly developing the typical inner turmoil expected from a teenager, flavored by the events they took part in and the fantasy world around them.

Short answer, there really isn't any major inner conflict in the first Harry Potter book, most likely because its intended audience was underdeveloped to appreciate such a device.